# expression language in jstl if statement not working

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jstl, tomcat9

I am trying to understand why this piece of code never prints the method request when run on tomcat 9:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
<title>Add Course</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:if test="${\"POST\".equalsIgnoreCase(pageContext.request.method) && pageContext.request.getParameter(\"submit\") != null}">
        <%= request.getMethod() %>
    </c:if>
    <form method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
        Credits : <input type="text" name="credits"> <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Tomcat 9 currently installed on my system, but it runs fine in Tomcat 8.5, and Jetty 9.4.17 printing "POST" whenever I post the form.

However, el language, despite resembling Java in many aspects and being able to call Java functions is NOT actually Java. You will encounter more success and consistency using it in a more idiomatic way. In your case, I'm pretty sure the following will work on any up-to-date JSP server:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
        <title>Add Course</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <c:if test="${'post' eq fn:toLowerCase(pageContext.request.method) and param.submit ne null}">
            ${pageContext.request.method}
        </c:if>
        <form method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
            Credits: <input type="text" name="credits" /><br />
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

- Using the `fn` taglib to compare strings in lower case
- Using single quotes around strings to avoid escaping
- Using el `eq` and `ne` operators for "equals" and "not equals"
- Using el `and` boolean operator
- Using el variable `param` to access request parameters
- Using `${...}` syntax to output values rather than scriptlets

Comment: I've just tested both on Tomcat 9.0.46 / AdoptOpenJDK 15.0.2.7-hotspot. Both work (as they both show the form, and print "POST" on top after you submit). I think the problem is not where you think it is...